# Getting error while extracting Date Fields from ignite cache using node express

Tags: java, node.js, express, ignite

We have an Oracle Table for which a corresponding cache/table is created in ignite and loaded using Cache JDBC POJO Store. On top of this cache a Rest API is built  using node express.

We are fetching the data from the cache using sql fields query and the programming language used is node js. We are able to fetch all the fields except the Date Fields and when we are trying to fetch the date fields we are getting the following error after execution of the statement

```js
const data = await cursorProductDetails.getAll();
```

> Error: Type type code -2 is not supported
>   Java Data type for this Field is java.sql.Date

In case if I cast the date field as varchar in sql fields query this error is not encountered. Even I didn't encounter this error when I am fetching the data using Java and Python. Can anyone please let me know how to resolve this issue without doing a cast as varchar and also the reason on why I am getting this error while using node express alone.

Following is the full code developed to build the rest-api.

```
enter code here
const express=require('express');
const url=require('url');
const querystring=require('querystring');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request=require('request');
const IgniteClient = require('apache-ignite-client');
const SqlFieldsQuery = IgniteClient.SqlFieldsQuery;
const IgniteClientConfiguration = IgniteClient.IgniteClientConfiguration;
const ENDPOINT='127.0.0.1';
const CACHE_NAME='PieProductDetailsLoadCache';
var _ = require('underscore');



const app=express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/productdetails',async function(req,res){


    const igniteClient =await new IgniteClient();

    try {

        //await res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        await igniteClient.connect(new IgniteClientConfiguration(ENDPOINT));
        const cache = igniteClient.getCache('PieProductDetailsLoadCache');
        const queryparametre=await req.query;
        const page=await parseInt(req.query.page);
        const limit=5000;

        const startindex=(page-1)*limit;
        const endindex=page*limit;

        const count_input_query_params=Object.keys(queryparametre).length;


        if(count_input_query_params==2

           && queryparametre.hasOwnProperty("page")
           && queryparametre.hasOwnProperty("countrycode") &&
           req.accepts('application/json')
          ){


        const queryProductDetails=new SqlFieldsQuery(`select * from  PieProductDetails where countrycode=? `
            ).setArgs(queryparametre.countrycode)
        ;

        const queryPerformance=new SqlFieldsQuery(`select * from  PIE.PieProductPerformance where countrycode=? `
                         ).setArgs(queryparametre.countrycode)
        ;

        queryProductDetails.setIncludeFieldNames(true);
        queryPerformance.setIncludeFieldNames(true);


        const cursorProductDetails = await cache.query(queryProductDetails);
        const cursorPerformance = await cache.query(queryPerformance);


        const dataProductDetails =await  cursorProductDetails.getAll();

        const dataPerformance =await  cursorPerformance.getAll();

        var prdfields=cursorProductDetails.getFieldNames();

        var perffields=cursorPerformance.getFieldNames();

        var res_data_prddetails=[];

        var res_data_perfdetails=[];

        await dataProductDetails.map(function(arr){
                                 //var prdobj={};
                                 //prdfields.forEach((k,v)=> prdobj[k]=arr[v]);
                                 var prdobj=_.object(prdfields,arr)
                                 res_data_prddetails.push(prdobj);


                                    }


          );

        await dataPerformance.map(function(arr){
            //var navobj={};
            //navfields.forEach((k,v)=> navobj[k]=arr[v]);
            var perfobj=_.object(perffields,arr)
            res_data_perfdetails.push(perfobj);


               }

        );

        nested_results=[];

        await  res_data_prddetails.map(function(arr){

            var tempobj=[arr];
            var perffiltereddata=_.where(res_data_perfdetails,

                {   productid:arr.productid


                }
            )
        ;

        tempobj[0].Performance=perffiltereddata;

        nested_results.push(tempobj[0]);

         }
        );

        const nested_results_Sorted=_.chain(nested_results).sortBy('productid')

         const results_paginated=nested_results_Sorted.slice(startindex,endindex);

         const rec_cnt=nested_results_Sorted.length;
         const prev_page=page-1;
         const next_page=page+1;



         const results={};

         if(page!=1){

             results.previous="/productdetails?page="+prev_page;

         }


        if(endindex<rec_cnt){

            results.next="/productdetails?page="+next_page;

        }



        results.totreccount=rec_cnt;
        results.reccountperpage=results_paginated.length;
        results.pagelimit=limit;


        results.Product=results_paginated;   

         if (results_paginated.length==0){
         res.status(404).json({"Message":"No Data exists"});
         }
         else{
            res.status(200).json(results);
         } ;

        }
        else if (!req.accepts('application/json')){
            res.status(400).json({
                "Message":"Application content should be application/json"
            });

        }
          else 
          {
                res.status(400).json({
                    "Message":"Invalid  query parametres.Accepts page and countrycode as query params "
                });
          }


          }




catch (err) {
    res.json({
        "Message ": err.message});
}

finally {

    igniteClient.disconnect();


}

});

//listen for requests
app.listen(process.env.port||4000,
    function(){
        console.log('now listensing to port '+4000);
    });
```

Comment: The only thing I can suggest with this is to read the source code. I think this is it? https://github.com/apache/ignite/search?l=JavaScript&p=2&q=date

Comment: You showed us one line of code. Where does `cursorProductDetails` come from? What module are you using to fetch the data from Ignite, `apache-ignite-client`? Have you seen these examples (note the SqlQueryEntriesExample.js one)? https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/modules/platforms/nodejs/examples

Comment: Updated the code in the post .Also can you please let me know is this the best and efficient way to build nested json using node express for a paginated Rest-API. Implementing the way in SqlQueryEntriesExample.js will not work for me as i need to once again create similar classes in node.js. In my case each class has almost 270 attributes as a result of which i am using sql fields query API instead.

Comment: Can you create a simple reproducer and file an Ignite ticket? I don't see any examples with Date and node.js, so it is possible it's broken.

Comment: One hack may be to use a `to_char()` on the date column? (Did you consider using [Oracle's node-oracledb module](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#apimanual) for Node.js?)

Comment: This module can be used if we are building rest api with source as Oracle DB but as we are building API by first loading data from Oracle DB to Ignite and on top on ignite we are building the API, I hope this module cannot be used.Please correct me if i am wrong.